# Recording Audio on the browser

Tags: django, audio, audio-recording

I have basic website I developed in Django and SQL lite.
I want to add this feature to it.

A user should be able to click a button and record a message that is no longer than 10 seconds and save it.

It can be saved on server as an audio file or can be saved on the database if that is more efficient and possible.

Can you please let me know if Django already has any component or plugin or something that I can use?

If it doesn't exist, what are my best options. If I need to write from the scratch, can you point me to any tutorials/blogs, etc?

Thanks for your time

- RM

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no such plugin for django. But it's not mainly django's work to do this. You can record audio via javascript using [Web Audio API](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/), or by using one of several projects (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20759947/921736)). Also if you have to support older browsers I think that your best bet is to use flash for this purpose (but some mobile browsers don't support it). So the best thing is to use some sort of fallback mode with html5&javascript implementation for browsers that support Audio API and use flash for others.