# Using Microphone API inside a UIWebView in pure JS

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

Is it possible to access Audio related stuffs with only JS? Or do i need to use the native code behind the scenes, using a UIWebView and the Objective-c lang to wrap the mic related methods? What i need is something simple, hear to sounds and do some algorithm to the signals received, but only inside a UIWebView, as a web app only. Is this a technical limitation, or is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you could use any of the HTML 5 WebAudio APIs from within the webview: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20759947/78496

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 11 supporting `getUserMedia()` you can now access the microphone using only JS in Safari. However, it will NOT not work in UIWebView, WKWebView or SFSafariViewController (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46717491/813988) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276130/ios11-getusermedia-with-apple-web-app-not-working)).

In Safari, once webcam/mic permission is given and the mic data kicks in you can encode the sound using JS libraries like [Recorder.js](https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/) (wav), [WebAudioRecorder.js](https://blog.addpipe.com/using-webaudiorecorder-js-to-record-audio-on-your-website/) (wav,mp3,Vorbis) or [vmsg](https://blog.addpipe.com/recording-mp3-audio-in-html5-using-vmsg-a-webassembly-library-based-on-lame/) (mp3).

You can also use the (native) [Media Recorder API](https://blog.addpipe.com/mediarecorder-api/) to capture (Opus) audio - together with this [neat polyfill](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill) for Safari 11 and Edge - but its still reliant on `getUserMedia()`.